# Why doesn't this custom static IP network configuration work?

Tags: server, networking, dns

I installed Ubuntu server 12.04. I configured my network like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 121.127.36.164
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 121.127.36.0
broadcast 121.127.36.255
gateway 121.127.36.1
dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220
```

with these configurations, I cannot connect to internet.

Whenever I do

```
ping www.google.com
```

it just waits. When I do

```
ping 77.245.149.23
```

or any other IP, it returns unreachable host error. Could you please help me fix this error?

Edit: I can ping the IP from my network. My modem is set to DHCP enabled dynamic IP.

Edit 2:
Sorry for my late explanations, but I must firstly explain the scenario:

There is a company with 20 staff. I developed a web application with PHP/CodeIgniter for them. Where they want to use it inside their local network.

I install an Ubuntu server 12.04, and want to make it a local server for this purpose. I need to assign a static IP address for this server, where it musnt changed.

I have a TP-Link Wireless Router, where the internet connection is provided through this router. It is DHCP enabled.

Now for this, what I need? How I must configure my server?

Comment: Please, post the output of: `ip addr`, `route -n` and `mtr -rn 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: ip addr:
`1: lo: I think it is not essential
2: eth0: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether d4:be:d9:96:33:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 121.127.36.164/64 brd 121.127.36.255 scope global eth0
inet6 fe80::d6be:d9ff:fe96:3314/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preffered_lft forever`

Comment: It would be better if you edit your answer and place this information there rather than in a comment. What about route and mtr?

Comment: Now I am out of office, I will update my post with your requested information. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem like this: I reserved an IP address to my server MAC address from my Router interface and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the guys [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2035775&page=2) which they helped me solve my problem.

Also, thank you all too.

Answer (score -1):

For safety, it is generally a good practice to have a non routable ip address for an internal LAN and then have a second adress for connecting to the Internet.

There are a series of three non routable addresses that are available:

- 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255,
- 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255.

Getting back to your initial question, I would check the contents of /etc/resolv.conf which is where the computer will indicate addresses of a namseserver or nameservers.

Comment: for this purpose, do I need two ethernet card? Now I have only one